# My output shows semi colon between two parties but also with one party

Tags: xml, xslt

My xml code can have one or more parties in the condition text. When there are more than one parties, then a semi colon is inserted between the two party names. If there is only one party, there is no need of a semi colon at the end of the name. 
My xslt is working fine when my xml document has 2 parties but it is still adding a semi colon when there is only one party. 
How do I only display a semi colon when the xml document has more than one party and not display a semi colon when the xml document has one party?

**Here is the output with 2 parties which is what I want with a semi colon between the names (party): However the addresses are out of order. Each party name should be followed by its address then a semi colon and then the other name with address and a period at the end.**

```
<ext:ProtectionOrderCondition>
        <ext:ConditionText>Respondent must not call or enter the place of employment of the following party(ies). This includes all land, parking lots, and buildings of the following addresses: Petitioner, Richard S; Dickens, Little;  3 Back Petitioner ST, My Town, MN, 55555; Foreign Address, FA line 2, FA line 3, FA line 4</ext:ConditionText>
        <ext:ConditionCode>04</ext:ConditionCode>
    </ext:ProtectionOrderCondition>
```

**Here is my output when xml document has only one party. Notice there is a semi colon at the end which should not be there:**

```
<ext:ProtectionOrderCondition>
        <ext:ConditionText>Petitioner is awarded sole physical and legal custody of the following child(ren): Brown, Rayne;  </ext:ConditionText>
        <ext:ConditionCode>09</ext:ConditionCode>
    </ext:ProtectionOrderCondition>
```

**my xml code with one party**

```
            <ProtectionOrder Op="E" InternalProtectionOrderID="2563">
            <ProtectionOrderParties>
                <ProtectionOrderParty InternalPartyID="1614450754">
                    <ProtectionOrderPartyNames>
                        <ProtectionOrderPartyName Current="true" InternalNameID="1615262152" FormattedName="Brown, Rayne"/>
                    </ProtectionOrderPartyNames>
                    <Added>12/29/2014</Added>
                    <ProtectionOrderConnection>
                        <Petitioner>true</Petitioner>
                        <FilingParty>false</FilingParty>
                        <ProtectedParty>true</ProtectedParty>
                        <Minor>false</Minor>
                    </ProtectionOrderConnection>
                    <MNProtectionOrderPartyAdditional xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
                        <DoesResideWithRespondent>false</DoesResideWithRespondent>
                        <ProtectedAddresses>
                            <Address InternalAddressID="1618211259" Type="Standard">
                                <Location Word="HOME">Home</Location>
                                <Confidential>false</Confidential>
                                <AddressLine2>1048 Regions RD</AddressLine2>
                                <AddressLine4>St Paul, MN, 55101</AddressLine4>
                                <Block>1048</Block>
                                <Street>Regions</Street>
                                <AddrSfxKy Word="RD">Road</AddrSfxKy>
                                <City>St Paul</City>
                                <State>MN</State>
                                <Zip>55101</Zip>
                                <Foreign>false</Foreign>
                                <TimestampCreate>12/29/2014 08:14:22:787</TimestampCreate>
                            </Address>
                        </ProtectedAddresses>
                    </MNProtectionOrderPartyAdditional>
                </ProtectionOrderParty>
            </ProtectionOrderParties>

            <MNProtectionOrderAdditional InternalID="2559" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
                <Conditions>
                    <Condition>
                        <Code Word="04AOAHC">04.A Respondent shall not call/enter place of employment</Code>
                        <Description>Respondent shall not call or enter Petitioner's place of employment which includes all land, parking lots, and buildings at:</Description>
                        <Addresses>
                            <Address InternalAddressID="1618211259"/>
                        </Addresses>
                    </Condition>
                    <Condition>
                        <Code Word="05OAHC">05 Petitioner is awarded sole physical and legal custody</Code>
                        <Description>Petitioner is awarded sole physical and legal custody of the following child(ren):</Description>
                        <Parties>
                            <Party InternalPartyID="1614450754"/>
                        </Parties>
                    </Condition>
                </Conditions>
            </MNProtectionOrderAdditional>
        </ProtectionOrder>
```

**My xml document with two parties:**

```
<ProtectionOrder Op="E" InternalProtectionOrderID="2571" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
    <ProtectionOrderParties>
        <ProtectionOrderParty InternalPartyID="1614451562">
            <ProtectionOrderPartyNames>
                <ProtectionOrderPartyName Current="true" InternalNameID="1615263003" FormattedName="Petitioner, Richard S"/>
            </ProtectionOrderPartyNames>
            <Added>12/29/2014</Added>
            <ProtectionOrderConnection>
                <Petitioner>true</Petitioner>
                <FilingParty>false</FilingParty>
                <ProtectedParty>true</ProtectedParty>
                <Minor>false</Minor>
            </ProtectionOrderConnection>
            <MNProtectionOrderPartyAdditional xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
                <DoesResideWithRespondent>false</DoesResideWithRespondent>
                <ProtectedAddresses>
                    <Address InternalAddressID="1618211271" Type="Standard">
                        <Location Word="HOME">Home</Location>
                        <Confidential>false</Confidential>
                        <AddressLine2>3 Back Petitioner ST</AddressLine2>
                        <AddressLine4>My Town, MN, 55555</AddressLine4>
                        <Block>3</Block>
                        <Street>Back Petitioner</Street>
                        <AddrSfxKy Word="ST">Street</AddrSfxKy>
                        <City>My Town</City>
                        <State>MN</State>
                        <Zip>55555</Zip>
                        <Foreign>false</Foreign>
                        <TimestampCreate>12/29/2014 10:11:36:903</TimestampCreate>
                    </Address>
                </ProtectedAddresses>
            </MNProtectionOrderPartyAdditional>
        </ProtectionOrderParty>
        <ProtectionOrderParty InternalPartyID="1614451515">
            <ProtectionOrderPartyNames>
                <ProtectionOrderPartyName Current="true" InternalNameID="1615262953" FormattedName="Dickens, Little"/>
            </ProtectionOrderPartyNames>
            <Added>12/29/2014</Added>
            <ProtectionOrderConnection>
                <Petitioner>false</Petitioner>
                <FilingParty>false</FilingParty>
                <ProtectedParty>true</ProtectedParty>
                <Minor>true</Minor>
            </ProtectionOrderConnection>
            <MNProtectionOrderPartyAdditional xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
                <DoesResideWithRespondent>false</DoesResideWithRespondent>
                <ProtectedAddresses>
                    <Address InternalAddressID="1618211278" Type="Foreign">
                        <Location Word="DAYCARE">Daycare</Location>
                        <Confidential>false</Confidential>
                        <AddressLine1>Foreign Address</AddressLine1>
                        <AddressLine2>FA line 2</AddressLine2>
                        <AddressLine3>FA line 3</AddressLine3>
                        <AddressLine4>FA line 4</AddressLine4>
                        <Foreign>true</Foreign>
                        <TimestampCreate>12/29/2014 11:49:37:020</TimestampCreate>
                    </Address>
                </ProtectedAddresses>
            </MNProtectionOrderPartyAdditional>
        </ProtectionOrderParty>
    </ProtectionOrderParties>

    <MNProtectionOrderAdditional InternalID="2567" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
        <Conditions>
            <Condition>
                <Code Word="03AEXPC">03.A Respondent must not commit domestic abuse</Code>
                <Description>Respondent must not commit acts of domestic abuse against the Protected Person(s). This means that Respondent may not harm or cause fear of harm to the Protected Person(s), and that Respondent may not use, attempt to use, or threaten to use physical force that would reasonably be expected to cause bodily injury to the Protected Person(s).</Description>
            </Condition>
            <Condition>
                <Code Word="03F1EXPC">03.F.1 Respondent must not call/enter place of employment</Code>
                <Description>Respondent must not call or enter the place of employment of the following party(ies). This includes all land, parking lots, and buildings of the following addresses:</Description>
                <Parties>
                    <Party InternalPartyID="1614451562"/>
                    <Party InternalPartyID="1614451515"/>
                </Parties>
                <Addresses>
                    <Address InternalAddressID="1618211271"/>
                    <Address InternalAddressID="1618211278"/>
                </Addresses>
            </Condition>
        </Conditions>
    </MNProtectionOrderAdditional>
</ProtectionOrder>
```

**My xslt code**

```
<xsl:for-each select="MNProtectionOrderAdditional/Conditions/Condition">
            <ext:ProtectionOrderCondition>
                <ext:ConditionText>
                    <xsl:variable name="vCondition">
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Description)"/>
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Parties/Party">
                            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ProtectionOrder/ProtectionOrderParties/ProtectionOrderParty[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
                                <xsl:value-of select="ProtectionOrderPartyNames/ProtectionOrderPartyName[@Current='true']/@FormattedName"/>
                                <!--<xsl:text>; </xsl:text>-->
                                <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                                <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Addresses/Address">
                            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ProtectionOrder/ProtectionOrderParties/ProtectionOrderParty/MNProtectionOrderPartyAdditional/ProtectedAddresses/Address[@InternalAddressID=current()/@InternalAddressID]">
                                <xsl:if test="AddressLine1">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine1"/>
                                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="AddressLine2">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine2"/>
                                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="AddressLine3">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine3"/>
                                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="AddressLine4">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="AddressLine4"/>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="substring($vCondition,string-length($vCondition)-1,2)='; '">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring($vCondition,1,string-length($vCondition)-2)"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$vCondition"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </ext:ConditionText>
                <ext:ConditionCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="document(concat($gEnvPath,'\ConfigFiles\MNCISCodes\ProtectionOrderConditionCodeMapping.xml'))
/ProtectionOrderConditionCodeMapping/Mapping[MNCISCode=current()/Code/@Word]/BCACode"/>
                </ext:ConditionCode>
            </ext:ProtectionOrderCondition>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

**What do I need to change in xslt so that the semi colon is only inserted when there is more than one name and not inserted when there is only one name?**

Comment: Please also show your XML input document - and more XSLT code, preferably a full, working stylesheet.

Comment: In your code the logic to decide when to output a semicolon is inside the _inner_ `for-each`, so it's checking the position within the list of `ProtectionOrderParty` matching the current `InternalPartyID`, not within the list of `Parties/Party`.  Without seeing the XML I can't know for sure, but it certainly seems suspect.

Answer (score 1):

**The standard idiom is *instead* of**

```
<xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
```

***use*:**

```
<xsl:if test="position() != last()">
     <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: @user3781064 There might be lots of other things we do not know about your XSLT code and about the nature of your XML input. Only if you show those things we can give a definitive answer.